# Understanding the third argument of functional programming methods like filter

Tags: javascript

Consider the example below:

```
arr.filter(function(el, index, self) {

  return index === self.indexOf(el);
});
```

How the word `self` represents the `arr` itself? 
Can it be something other like `array`?

Comment: Did you *try* using some other name, like `array`, before you posted this question?

Comment: @squint No,but I've read some documents seeking an answer

Comment: Well wouldn't it have been much faster and easier to try it first?

Comment: @JJJ I'd like to delete this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Self is not a keyword in JavaScript. The function arguments are (element, index, array), naming the third argument self results in your example. You can use self however you want.

Comment: But how it can represents the array `arr`?

Comment: The functions footprint just is like this. You are handing a callback-function to the filter-function. The filter-function then iterates over the array, for every element it calls the callback with three arguments, the first one being the current element, the second one the current elements index, and the third one the array itself. For more information, see https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter